# Find string in text file then find 1st instance of another string then get the text that follows

Tags: php, string, search

I need to locate a string in a text file. Once found then find the first instance of a second string below the first string, then get the text that immediately follows the second string and add that text to a variable that I can use later.

Here is a sample of the text file I will need to search within ...

```
Tournament=Test
Number=897  // I need to locate this Number.
Currency=Primary
BuyIn=0.01+0.02
PrizeBonus=0
MultiplyBonus=No
Entrants=2
Late=0
Tickets=0
Removed=0
Rebuys=0
AddOns=0
RebuyCost=0+0
NetBonus=0
StopOnChop=No
Start=2020-03-02 04:07:56
Place2=Tuck (0)
Place1=TuckStream (0.02) // Then I need to locate "Place1=", then get the name that follows.
Stop=2020-03-02 04:08:47
```

**Summary:** I need to grab the Winner's name from a text file after locating the proper tournament number within the file. There are several tourneys stored in the same text file. The text file is updated after a tourney completes, then an event runs and provides me with the new tourney number in a string.

Right now I'm just grabbing all the contents of the file (like above) and posting the entire thing to discord with a webhook. I'd prefer to only post the Winner's name, "TuckStream" as in the sample above.

I also need to perform another action with just the Players name so I need it added to a $Winner variable (for instance). Here's the current code within the event handler that posts the entire contents of the file...

```
case "TourneyFinish":
  fwrite($f,"Event = " .  $event . "\n");
  fwrite($f,"Name = "  .  $_POST["Name"] . "\n");
  fwrite($f,"Number = " . $_POST["Number"] . "\n");
  fwrite($f,"Time = " .   $_POST["Time"] . "\n");
  fwrite($f,"\n");
  $TourneyName = $_POST["Name"];

  // wait for file to be written to disk
  sleep(10);
  // find latest file     
  $path = "C:/TourneyResults"; 
  $latest_ctime = 0;
  $latest_filename = '';    

  $d = dir($path);
  while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
    $latest_filename = $entry;
  }
}

    // post message in discord chan #tourney-annoucements
    $getinfo = file_get_contents($path . "/" . $latest_filename);
    $message = "**$TourneyName Results** \n $getinfo";
    $data = ['content' => $message];
    $options = [
                'http' => [
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
                'content' => json_encode($data)
                ]
            ];
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/mywebhook', false, $context);

  break;
```

Comment: So which problem do you have?

Comment: You mean you need a regex to find 897 then Place1=(this)? Like this: https://regex101.com/r/BnqIhg/1

Comment: That looks like it does what I need @Andreas, thanks! I know nothing about regex, but will try to read up on how to use it. I will give your solution below a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: @TuckFheman ok tell me if you need more help with the code

Comment: Ok thanks @Andreas that worked great! I borked it originally trying to put in the tournament number variable, but once I realized what I had done I got it going now. I can't thank you enough! =)

Comment: @Andreas with `/Number=(\d+)` it's grabbing the Winner from the first result in the file always, instead of the last/current result, I didn't realize that initially. How do I specify for it to search for the last tourney # played, which I've assigned to $TNumber with `$TNumber = $_POST["Number"];`?

Comment: Got it, sorry I'm a n00b. `Number=($TNumber)` did the trick!

Comment: @TuckFheman i wasn't sure if you had the number or needed to get the number from the file. But good that you solved it. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: I did accept it, but I'm so new here it said it won't count it yet or something along those lines. =/  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all` to get both the number and the winner in one go.

```
$getinfo = file_get_contents($path . "/" . $latest_filename);

preg_match_all("/Number=(\d+).*?Place1=(.*?)\s/s", $getinfo, $info);

$message = "**$TourneyName Results** \nTournament Number " . $info[1][0] . "\nWinner " .$info[2][0];
echo $message;
```

returns:

```
**something undefined Results** 
Tournament Number 897
Winner TuckStream
```

The regex pattern first finds **Number**  and grabs the digits that follow with this part: `Number=(\d+)`.
Then it skips ahead to Place1 with `.*?`, and use this part `Place1=(.*?)\s` to find the winners name.
The last part is `/s` which means it searches multi-lined.